# Technical vulnerability details on Sitecore critical vulnerability (SC2016-001-128003)

Tags: security

What are the technical vulnerability which are covered by the [critical vulnerability (SC2016-001-128003)](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/496731)? The KB article doesn't cover what the vulnerability is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a 0-day vulnerability

Comment: I do agree, however, it might be relevant for everyone running older versions of Sitecore. From that perspective, the explanation here can be very relevant for a broad audience - they might be triggered to upgrade/patch their environment based on this information

Comment: Why on earth has this been deemed off-topic? If we cannot discuss vulnerabilities on a site like SE, then what is the use? I'm not saying we should publish ready-to-run exploitation code, but to discuss the technical impact of a 0-day exploit, and the possible functional degradation of the hotfix is IMHO what this site is for (amongst other topics of course).

Comment: The vulnerability is labelled "Critical" - as in "Allows unauthorized code execution on target environment". That really is all, anyone should need to know. Given that this is a 0 day vulnerability that by and large has not been patched _anywhere_ yet - discussing the inner workings and details, how to exploit it etc, is inappropriate. For this site and any site.

Comment: That said - it is the first time we've dealt with this particular type of question - the community has yet to agree on a standard on this subject. Right now I think the consensus is, to "err on the side of caution" - until we've had time to debate how we want to deal with these questions moving forward.

Comment: I have raised this as a discussion on meta. http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/116/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-on-security-vulnerabilities

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** I have removed technical details about the vulnerability, since it is still present on many Sitecore installations world-wide.

## The Quick-and-Dirty fix

If you want to remove the vulnerability quickly and without restarting your Sitecore instances, just delete `PushSession.ashx`—it's used very rarely anyway, and only in multi-cluster setups. You can apply the full fix later.

Comment: Who can call it? Is it filtered by anything or is it just open to the world?

Comment: @VicentGaliana It is open.